# Excell - How to color a cell if all the cells to the right of it are blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors, conditional-formatting

This is what I tried putting in the conditional formatting:

```
COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("RC[1]",0):INDIRECT("RC[100]",0))=0
```

I know this is only checking for the next 100 cells but I don't know another way.

Anyways it tells me I can't have ranges in my conditional formatting formula.

Also, I wanted to add a condition to only trigger this when the current cell is not blank so I was thinking an AND statement with INDIRECT("RC[0]",0)? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
 `=AND(C3<>"",COUNTA(D3:XFD3)=0)`

C3 is the cell which you want to color if not empty and the cells on its right are blank
`COUNTA(D3:XFD3)=0` to check if all the cells to the right of C3 are blank
D3 is the cell next to C3 to the right
XFD3 the last cell in the same row
`And` will evaluate to True if both condition are True

Select the cells which you want to set the Conditional Formatting to
Write the above formula in the Conditional Formatting, New Rule and set the color
Another way to do it
You can create a cell before C3 for example B3 and write the formula in it
In C3 The Rule will be `=B3=true`  and Format color

Comment: ... but you can't use arrays in conditional formatting formulas

Comment: did you try this formula? it is not Array Formula, just CountA